# Python - Beginner Scraping with Beautiful Soup 4 - onmouseover

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i'm a beginner python (3) user and i'm currently trying to scrape some sports stats for my fantasy football season. Previously I did this in a round about way (downloading in HT-track, converting to excel and using VBA to combine my data). But now I'm trying to learn python to improve my coding abilities.

I want to scrape [this page](http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=6172][1]) but running into some difficulty in selecting only the rows/tables I want. Here is how my code currently stands. It still has a bit of code where I have been trying to play around with it.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  # import the library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   # Import BS
from bs4 import SoupStrainer    # Import Soup Strainer

page = urlopen('http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=6172') # access the website
only_tables = SoupStrainer('table') # parse only table elements when parsing
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')   # parse the html


# for row in soup('table',{'class':'tbody'}[0].tbody('tr')):
#   tds = row('td')
#   print (tds[0].string, tds[1].string)

# create variables to keep the data in

team = []
player = []
kicks = []
handballs = []
disposals = []
marks = []
goals = []
tackles = []
hitouts = []
inside50s = []
freesfor = []
freesagainst = []
fantasy = []
supercoach = []

table = soup.find_all('tr')


# print(soup.prettify())

print(table)
```

Right now I can select all 'tr' from the page, however I'm having trouble only selecting the rows which have the following attribute:

```
<tr bgcolor="#ffffff" onmouseout="this.bgColor='#ffffff';" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#cbcdd0';">
```

"onmouseover" seems to be the only attribute which is common/unique to the table I want to scrape.

Does anyone know how I can alter this line of code, to select this attribute?

```
table = soup.find_all('tr')
```

From here I am confident I can place the data into a dataframe which hopefully I can export to CSV.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have looked through the BS4 documentation with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained on the [`BeautifulSoup` documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29)

You may use this :

```
table = soup.findAll("tr", {"bgcolor": "#ffffff", "onmouseout": "this.bgColor='#ffffff'", "onmouseover": "this.bgColor='#cbcdd0';"})
```

More, you can also use the following approach:

```
tr_tag = soup.findAll(lambda tag:tag.name == "tr" and tag["bgcolor"] == "#ffffff") and tag["onmouseout"] = "this.bgColor='#ffffff'" and tag["onmouseover"] = "this.bgColor='#cbcdd0';"
```

The advantage of the above approach is that it uses the full power of BS and it's giving you the result in a very optimized way

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I see what I was doing wrong with the attrs section now.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"onmouseover" : "this.bgColor='#cbcdd0';"})
```

Comment: Thank you very much (and @Dex' ter)! I swear I tried similar things but it never worked for me.