# Scraping in BeautifulSoup 4 with Python - Beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

thanks for your help with the last question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42362448/python-beginner-scraping-with-beautiful-soup-4-onmouseover)). However I'm currently stuck in getting my final dataframe ready. I've been able to extract all the data from the original table and display it how I want, however I now want to add the home team and the away team to the df but seem to be unable to figure it out. Here is what I have currently, and [here is the site](http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid=6172) I wish to scrape.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  # import the library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   # Import BS
from bs4 import SoupStrainer    # Import Soup Strainer
import pandas as pd    # import pandas as a package

basescrape = 'http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid='
matchid = '6172'

scrapeweb1 = basescrape+matchid

page = urlopen(scrapeweb1) # access the website
only_tables = SoupStrainer('table', attrs={"width" : "583"}) # parse only table elements when parsing
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser', parse_only=only_tables)   # parse the html

only_teams = SoupStrainer('table', attrs={"width" : "376"}) # parse only team qtr score elements when parsing
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser', parse_only=only_teams)   # parse the html


# only valid rows with player data in

table = soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"onmouseover" : "this.bgColor='#cbcdd0';"})


# create variables to keep the data in

hometeam = []
awayteam = []

player = []
kicks = []
handballs = []
disposals = []
marks = []
goals = []
behinds = []
tackles = []
hitouts = []
inside50s = []
freesfor = []
freesagainst = []
fantasy = []
supercoach = []

# Find all the <tr> tag pairs, skip the first one, then for each.
for row in soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"onmouseover" : "this.bgColor='#cbcdd0';"}):
    # Create a variable of all the <td> tag pairs in each <tr> tag pair,
    col = row.find_all('td')

    # Create a variable of the string inside 1st <td> tag pair,
    column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
    # and append it to player variable
    player.append(column_1)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 2nd <td> tag pair,
    column_2 = col[1].string.strip()
    # and append it to kicks variable
    kicks.append(column_2)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 3rd <td> tag pair,
    column_3 = col[2].string.strip()
    # and append it to handballs variable
    handballs.append(column_3)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 4th <td> tag pair,
    column_4 = col[3].string.strip()
    # and append it to disposals variable
    disposals.append(column_4)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_5 = col[4].string.strip()
    # and append it to marks variable
    marks.append(column_5)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_6 = col[5].string.strip()
    # and append it to goals variable
    goals.append(column_6)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_7 = col[6].string.strip()
    # and append it to behinds variable
    behinds.append(column_7)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_8 = col[7].string.strip()
    # and append it to tackles variable
    tackles.append(column_8)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_9 = col[8].string.strip()
    # and append it to hitouts variable
    hitouts.append(column_9)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_10 = col[9].string.strip()
    # and append it to inside50s variable
    inside50s.append(column_10)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_11 = col[10].string.strip()
    # and append it to freesfo variable
    freesfor.append(column_11)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_12 = col[11].string.strip()
    # and append it to freesagainst variable
    freesagainst.append(column_12)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_13 = col[12].string.strip()
    # and append it to fantasy variable
    fantasy.append(column_13)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_14 = col[13].string.strip()
    # and append it to supercoach variable
    supercoach.append(column_14)

# Find all the <tr> tag pairs, then for each.
for row in soup2.find_all("tr", class_= "leftbold"):
    # Create a variable of all the <td> tag pairs in each <tr> tag pair,
    col2 = row.find_all('td')

    # Create a variable of the string inside 1st <td> tag pair,
    hometeam = col2[0].string.strip()
    # and append it to player variable
    # hometeam.append(column2_1)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 2nd <td> tag pair,
    awayteam = col2[1].string.strip()
    # and append it to kicks variable
    # awayteam.append(column2_2)


# Create a variable of the value of the columns
columns = {'match_id': matchid, 'home_team': hometeam, 'away_team': awayteam, 'player': player, 'kicks': kicks, 'handballs': handballs, 'disposals': disposals, 'marks': marks, 'goals': goals, 'behinds': behinds, 'tackles': tackles, 'hitouts': hitouts, 'inside_50s': inside50s, 'frees_for': freesfor, 'frees_against': freesagainst, 'fantasy': fantasy, 'supercoach': supercoach}

# Create a dataframe from the columns variable - n
df = pd.DataFrame(columns, columns = ['match_id', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'player', 'kicks', 'handballs', 'disposals', 'marks', 'goals', 'behinds', 'tackles', 'hitouts', 'inside_50s', 'frees_for', 'frees_against', 'fantasy', 'supercoach'])

print(df)

# print(soup.prettify())

# print(table)
```

Obviously the dataframe won't work as the arrays aren't all the same length. How can I scrape the home and away team and save it to a variable so that it works in the same way that the matchid works?

Alterantively is there a way to make the "hometeam" variable appear in the first 22 rows and the "awayteam" in the 23-44th rows? that way the player is attributed to a single team?

I feel i'm doing this section here incorrectly:

```
# Find all the <tr> tag pairs, then for each.
for row in soup2.find_all("tr", class_= "leftbold"):
    # Create a variable of all the <td> tag pairs in each <tr> tag pair,
    col2 = row.find_all('td')

    # Create a variable of the string inside 1st <td> tag pair,
    hometeam = col2[0].string.strip()
    # and append it to player variable
    # hometeam.append(column2_1)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 2nd <td> tag pair,
    awayteam = col2[1].string.strip()
    # and append it to kicks variable
    # awayteam.append(column2_2)
```

Thanks very much for your help.

(also bonus question, I couldn't get the scrapeweb1 to work using the ".join" operator, as I've read using the "+" on strings is not best practise. What I tried to use, but failed, is below)

```
scrapeweb1 = "".join(basescrape, matchid)
```

Edit: so I inspected the source and it appears there is some incorrect HTML in that table...

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="376" id="matchscoretable">
<tr>
<th class="leftbold" height="23" width="100">Team</td>
```

it uses a "/td" rather than "/th" which when parsed through beautiful soup causes the table tag to close...

```
[<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="matchscoretable" width="376">
<tr>
<th class="leftbold" height="23" width="100">Team</th></tr></table>]
```

I may have to look at another way of getting the home and away teams names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  # import the library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   # Import BS
from bs4 import SoupStrainer    # Import Soup Strainer
import pandas as pd    # import pandas as a package

basescrape = 'http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid='
matchid = '6172'
url = ''.join([basescrape,matchid])

# changed the table width to 585 to get first row with team name
only_tables = SoupStrainer('table', attrs={"width" : "585"}) # parse only table elements when parsing
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), 'html.parser', parse_only=only_tables)   # parse the html
# use the table titles as anchor points
teams = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'innertbtitle', 'align':'left'})
# create an empty list for the players
player_list = []
# iterate through anchor points
for team in teams:
    # extract team name from the table title
    team_name = team.text.strip().split(' ', maxsplit=1)[0]
    # get the rows from the next table relative to anchor point
    trs = team.find_next('table', attrs={'width':583}).find_all('tr')
    # create list of labels using first row in table
    labels = [td.text for td in trs.pop(0).find_all('td')]
    # iterate through the remaining rows
    for row in trs:
        # build dictionary using label as key and text of each cell as value
        player_dict = {label:value.text for label,value in 
                       zip(labels, row.find_all('td'))}
        # add team name to dictionary
        player_dict['team'] = team_name
        # append dictionary to the list
        player_list.append(player_dict)

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(player_list)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to do this, it's my understanding this scrapes all the data and places it in a nice dataframe?

Edit: I just managed to get some time to run it, wow that is so much neater! Thanks very much for your help. Sorry for being such a pain but would you help me understand each line? I'm desperately trying to improve my python coding.

Comment: My understanding so far (using "players_list = []" as line 1)

1. Creates a empty variable called "players_list"
2. Looks through each "team" in "teams" BS element
3. the team_name is allocated by the header, which is split by a space, the first value is returned (team name)
4. then defining a new BS element which is the rows in the actual table we want scraped
5. assigning the headers of each row to create labels for the DF
6. creating a loop to go through each row of the table
7. creating another loop to assign the value of each column to the header and store it in "player_dict" ...

Comment: 8. Retrieves each value from each 'td' bracket and stores it in the correct label
9. Creates a new column in 'player_dict' called 'team' and assigns it to the row
10. Adds the completed row to "player_list" variable

11. Creates a dataframe for the player list

Is that all correct? have I missed someone?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, here's the completed code now...

```
from urllib.request import urlopen  # import the library
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   # Import BS
from bs4 import SoupStrainer    # Import Soup Strainer
import pandas as pd    # import pandas as a package

basescrape = 'http://www.footywire.com/afl/footy/ft_match_statistics?mid='
matchid = '6172'

scrapeweb1 = basescrape+matchid

page = urlopen(scrapeweb1) # access the website
page2 = urlopen(scrapeweb1) # access the website

only_tables = SoupStrainer('table', attrs={"width" : "583"}) # parse only table elements when parsing

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser', parse_only=only_tables)   # parse the html
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2, 'html.parser') # parse the html


# only valid rows with player data in

table = soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"onmouseover" : "this.bgColor='#cbcdd0';"})


# create variables to keep the data in

Table1 = soup2.find_all('table', attrs={'width':"375"})[1]

hometeam = Table1.find_all('td', attrs={'width':"124"})[0].string.strip()
awayteam = Table1.find_all('td', attrs={'width':"124"})[1].string.strip()


player = []
kicks = []
handballs = []
disposals = []
marks = []
goals = []
behinds = []
tackles = []
hitouts = []
inside50s = []
freesfor = []
freesagainst = []
fantasy = []
supercoach = []

# Find all the <tr> tag pairs, skip the first one, then for each.
for row in soup.find_all("tr", attrs={"onmouseover" : "this.bgColor='#cbcdd0';"}):
    # Create a variable of all the <td> tag pairs in each <tr> tag pair,
    col = row.find_all('td')

    # Create a variable of the string inside 1st <td> tag pair,
    column_1 = col[0].string.strip()
    # and append it to player variable
    player.append(column_1)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 2nd <td> tag pair,
    column_2 = col[1].string.strip()
    # and append it to kicks variable
    kicks.append(column_2)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 3rd <td> tag pair,
    column_3 = col[2].string.strip()
    # and append it to handballs variable
    handballs.append(column_3)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 4th <td> tag pair,
    column_4 = col[3].string.strip()
    # and append it to disposals variable
    disposals.append(column_4)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_5 = col[4].string.strip()
    # and append it to marks variable
    marks.append(column_5)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_6 = col[5].string.strip()
    # and append it to goals variable
    goals.append(column_6)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_7 = col[6].string.strip()
    # and append it to behinds variable
    behinds.append(column_7)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_8 = col[7].string.strip()
    # and append it to tackles variable
    tackles.append(column_8)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_9 = col[8].string.strip()
    # and append it to hitouts variable
    hitouts.append(column_9)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_10 = col[9].string.strip()
    # and append it to inside50s variable
    inside50s.append(column_10)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_11 = col[10].string.strip()
    # and append it to freesfo variable
    freesfor.append(column_11)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_12 = col[11].string.strip()
    # and append it to freesagainst variable
    freesagainst.append(column_12)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_13 = col[12].string.strip()
    # and append it to fantasy variable
    fantasy.append(column_13)

    # Create a variable of the string inside 5th <td> tag pair,
    column_14 = col[13].string.strip()
    # and append it to supercoach variable
    supercoach.append(column_14)




# Create a variable of the value of the columns
columns = {'match_id': matchid, 'home_team': hometeam, 'away_team': awayteam, 'player': player, 'kicks': kicks, 'handballs': handballs, 'disposals': disposals, 'marks': marks, 'goals': goals, 'behinds': behinds, 'tackles': tackles, 'hitouts': hitouts, 'inside_50s': inside50s, 'frees_for': freesfor, 'frees_against': freesagainst, 'fantasy': fantasy, 'supercoach': supercoach}

# Create a dataframe from the columns variable - n
df = pd.DataFrame(columns, columns = ['match_id', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'player', 'kicks', 'handballs', 'disposals', 'marks', 'goals', 'behinds', 'tackles', 'hitouts', 'inside_50s', 'frees_for', 'frees_against', 'fantasy', 'supercoach'])

print(df)
```